# NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName , How to strike out the string in iOS 10.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablestring

I have used this line of code before release of iOS 10.3 ,and worked fine.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",strMRP,strOffer]];

[attributeString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(0, strMRP.length)];

[attributeString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] range:NSMakeRange(strMRP.length, strOffer.length+1)];

[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: NSUnderlineStyleDouble]
                        range:NSMakeRange(0,strMRP.length)];
```

But now it is stopped working ,is there any alternate way to do the strike out ?

Comment: So, what is the error exactly?... I have successfully reproduced your snippet in a swift playground (iOS 10.3) and works just fine.

Comment: @Alladinian no its not working ,can you test it on device

Comment: Yep, it fails on a device, so it's definitely a bug

Comment: It also happens with subscript and superscript attributes

Comment: See for a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478697/swift-3-1-nssuperscript-in-nsattributedstring-not-working-as-expected/43074313

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 10.3: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName is not rendered if applied to a sub range of NSMutableAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/ios-10-3-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-is-not-rendered-if-applied-to-a-sub)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is the **bug in iOS 10.3** , **`NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`** (any `NSUnderlineStyle` cases) is not working any more on iOS SDK 10.3.

> if anyone found the updated answer related to this , please inform here, I will update my answer.

Product Version: 10.3

Created: 14-Mar-2017

Originated: 14-Mar-2017

Open Radar Link: http://www.openradar.appspot.com/31034683

Radar status is Currently **Open state**

you can see the alternate sample also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074652/ios-10-3-nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-is-not-rendered-if-applied-to-a-sub/43359207#43359207) may be it useful.

Comment: Not tested on a device, but it definitely works fine in an iOS playground (10.3)

Comment: @Alladinian - I agree your comment , I taken the link from open radar the Status: `Open`

Comment: @KishoreKumar - pardon

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ??

Comment: @KishoreKumar - yes, absolutely, its is open state, may be next version it will be fix

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik so if any bug registered in open radar ,then it is accepted by apple ?

Comment: @KishoreKumar - yes, bro, if it is closed or working the radar will be closed

Comment: happands me to , have a solution ?

Comment: @Kishore Kumar me to, this is the only way (i think).

Comment: [add this link in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43359207/1066828), but didn't tested yet...

Answer (score 5):

I found one workaround on [developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/72643), which works for me. Adding of `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` to string attributes fixed this problem :)

Comment: This works, thank you! Before, I tried some other suggested fixes and they didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It work fine with

```
   NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",strMRP,strOffer]];

[attributeString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(0, strMRP.length)];

[attributeString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] range:NSMakeRange(strMRP.length, strOffer.length+1)];

[attributeString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName
                        value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: NSUnderlineStyleNone]
                        range:NSMakeRange(0,strMRP.length)];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: NSUnderlineStyleDouble]
                        range:NSMakeRange(0,strMRP.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 10.3 onward you need to add NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",strMRP,strOffer]];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(0, strMRP.length)];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] range:NSMakeRange(strMRP.length, strOffer.length+1)];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName
                    value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: NSUnderlineStyleNone]
                    range:NSMakeRange(0,strMRP.length)];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                    value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: NSUnderlineStyleDouble]
                    range:NSMakeRange(0,strMRP.length)];
```

Once you add NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName then it works for single line, double line ect.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this is an iOS 10.3 bug.

We needed an immediate workaround, so just in case anyone is looking for hints:
Our Label had attributes set through both `NSMutableAttributedString` as well as `NSMutableParagraphStyle`. The bug did not occur when using no / an "empty" paragraph style (instance without any properties set).

So in this scenario, omitting the paragraph style and working around the then missing paragraph properties resolved the issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this :-

> NSMutableAttributedString *costPrice = [[NSMutableAttributedString
>   alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"₹ %@",strDetails]];
>   [costPrice addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName
>                               value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0,costPrice.length)];

This is temp solution . Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

***You can pass it to function & Enjoy !!!

```
func customString(currentprice:String,oldPrice:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString{
        // 1
        let NewString = currentprice + "  " + oldPrice

        let string = NewString as NSString
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string as String)

        // 2
        let firstAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 238/255, green: 140/255, blue: 84/255, alpha: 1),NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:1]
        let secondAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: 1]

        // 3
        attributedString.addAttributes(firstAttributes, range: string.rangeOfString(currentprice))
        attributedString.addAttributes(secondAttributes, range: string.rangeOfString(oldPrice))

        return attributedString
    }
```

and use like:

```
YourUILabel.attributedText   = customString("300", oldPrice: "400")
```