# Set NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName for UILabel not work in iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10.3

This is example code :

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str=[[NSMutableAttributedString   alloc]initWithString:@"$198"];   

[str addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:@2 range:NSMakeRange(0,[str length])];  

yourLabel.attributedText = str;
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070335/how-to-strike-out-the-string-in-ios-10-3

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ok, Thanks!