# iOS10.3 system rich text strikethrough can not be displayed

Tags: ios, nsmutableattributedstring, ios10.3

`Apple` recently released `iOS 10.3` version, before the use of `NSMutableAttributedString` set the strikers do not show the

```
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternSolid) range:NSMakeRange(length1 + 7, length2 + 5)];
```

Tried a lot of ways are not resolved, hoping to get everyone's help

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070335/nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-how-to-strike-out-the-string-in-ios-10-3

Comment: Its open bug in iOS 10.3 Here, its open radar link: http://www.openradar.appspot.com/31034683

Comment: Fixed in 10.3.2 beta 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName , How to strike out the string in iOS 10.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070335/nsstrikethroughstyleattributename-how-to-strike-out-the-string-in-ios-10-3)

Answer (score 5):

iOS 10.3 onward you should have to add one more attribute.

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@0 range:NSMakeRange(length1 + 7, length2 + 5)];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternSolid) range:NSMakeRange(length1 + 7, length2 + 5)];
```

Comment: Working fine for me.